# Auto Open Setup after Download [PHP]

Tags: php, google-chrome, automation

If you visit https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/#eula to download Google Chrome, it auto start setup file upon click accept & install button.
My Question is that is it possible for me to open file to user's pc if after download automatically upon download finish just like Chrome?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Just set the right headers to your file.
As an example, if your file is a pdf:

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"my_document.pdf\"");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
//... code for generating the pdf...
```

The headers must be set at the beginning of your php page

Comment: It will just download file but I want to auto open file to user's PC. means it must automatically open that PDF File on User's PC.